# How to run a Word macro from the command line?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, vba, macros

I'm trying to save and close all open Word files (to start I only target one of them).

The macro I made works when ran from Word (clicking "Execute"), but it won't run when called from the command line with this:

```
winword.exe /n /mMacro3
```

- Operative system: Windows 11
- Word version: 2019
- Word opens and says that "the macros of this project have been disabled".
- I have tried using a different target file and restarting Word.
- The target file is "Doc2.docm".
- I think it is available in "Normal.dotm" because it appears when I select this option in the
  [macro menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPfei.png).
- In macro settings, all macros are allowed and also checked the "Trust VBA project DOM" (translated) option just in case.
- I don't have the option some people in forums have of a "Security" section (not tab) in the first tab of the file's properties in the file explorer with the option to unblock the file.
- Developer->Protect->Restrict editing's options are completely off.

The macro file:

```
Public Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'
'
Dim doc As Document
Dim docName As String

docName = "Doc2.docm"

For Each doc In Documents
    If doc.Name = docName Then
        doc.Save
        doc.Close
    End If
Next doc

MsgBox "The ''" & docName & "'' document was not founr.", vbExclamation
End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: I'm fairly sure you're running into a security check here and that its going to be hard to do with a word macro. Given that what you want to do is just close word and save, maybe go the powershell route. Powershell can find all word instances and send a soft close, which will trigger word to close all documents. Any document not saved will give a Do you want to save [yes] [no] button. You can then use powershell to detect these popups and send a y to its dialog or enter to save the document. Also, it may be possible to start word from powershell and have more control over it.

Comment: @LPChip Interesting, I'll look into it. Thanks.

Comment: Wow that's just beautiful, thanks again

Comment: Consider simply naming the macro AutoExec in your Normal.dotm.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon Really? So that everytime he starts an instance of word, it closes all his word documents? That would be really annoying.

Comment: @LPChip My bad. Misread the question. Why start separate instances of Word, though. That is generally poor programming.

Comment: Why do you need to run this from the Command line? I misread your question earlier because most use of command line macros is for when Word is not open.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon what I think it is that they want to achieve, is have something they can run that will quickly save all documents and close word. Possible scenarios: quickly turn off the compter at the end of the day.

Comment: Easy enough to do from within Word, in ih toh.